# How to load Html page saved in sdcard on android?

Tags: android, html, webview

I saved some html pages in sdcard. so , i want to display those pages through webview . can any help to do this task ?

Thanking you ,
Srinivas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a ContentProvider, see [this page](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/) for step by step howto

Answer (score 1):

1. Read file into the String webSite (like this http://www.anddev.org/read_a_txt_file_from_sd_card_in_a_real_device-t6619.html )
2. WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
3. webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
    webview.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/packagename/files/example.html");
```