# How to deploy HTML5 application in sdcard of device and access it as like .apk apps

Tags: jquery, android, html

I have some HTML5 based pages i want it to deploy it in sdcard of device and access it as like normal .apk apps

Comment: thanks for the replay ya these pages are static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to access it like an application unless you create an application with a webview and load the html pages that way. Even then that may not work.

e.g - [How to load Html page saved in sdcard on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141506/how-to-load-html-page-saved-in-sdcard-on-android)

You could use the browser and access the files locally.

e.g. - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/how-can-i-open-an-html-file-i-have-copied-from-pc-to-sd-card-of-phone

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser

Or you could use one of those web app developer tool things e.g.
http://phonegap.com/

http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/

Answer (score 2):

Use [PhoneGap API](http://phonegap.com/) or [SensaTouch API](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/) to build the Android application with html pages using [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Then the apk file can be generated using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks every one i got solution fetch html pages from sdcard that could be better way i used the following code for the same.The below code is also use full activate java script settings and all

```
package com.WebView.ebook;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment; 
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebVieweBookActivity extends Activity {
WebView wvMain;

String urlfunBook="file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.html";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wvMain=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings8 = wvMain.getSettings();
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);

    wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

    wvMain.getSettings().setCacheMode(wvMain.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings8.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    wvMain.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wvMain.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    wvMain.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wvMain.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wvMain.loadUrl(urlfunBook);

    wvMain.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        System.exit(4);
        } 
    else {
        wvMain.loadUrl(urlfunBook);
    }
   }
 }
```